# put firebase data to an array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to retrive data from firebase. but some how it's not working. here what i have done.

here is my database from firebase

[image: here is my database from firebase]

**here is my object class**

```
class UserObj: NSObject {

   var address: String?
    var name: String?
    var phone: String?
    var userId: String?   
}
```

// here is my viewController class

```
  var refhandel:DatabaseHandle!
    var ref:DatabaseReference!

    var proModel = [UserObj]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        getProfileD()
    }

    func getProfileD(){
        refhandel = ref.child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let item = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{

                let user = UserObj()
                user.setValuesForKeys(item)
                self.proModel.append(user)

                for i in self.proModel {
                    print(i)
                }
            }     
        })


    }
```

i am getting this error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key phone.

Comment: Can you please tell us on which line you are getting this error ?

Comment: Actually i got this error after crashing the app its goes to app AppDelegate class.
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Seller.UserObj 0x604000104da0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key phone.'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Have you checked in your Firebase elements that all contain an address, a name, a phone and a userId ?

Comment: i put a screenshot of my firebase database here.. you can see in starting point of my question

Comment: Yes, but I can't see for the N3... if a key is missing there, it can trigger the error. You have to make sure all your Firebase elements contains the key you are trying to retrieve

Comment: N3 are same thing

Comment: A gut feeling says that the value of `phone` might be converted to a number somewhere. Can you: 1) check if you're storing `phone` as a string value in all child nodes, 2) check if the problem disappears if you prefix all `phone` values with a fixed string, e.g. `nr`.

Comment: Can you print item just to be sure it's an item ?

Comment: i got data when i print item. @Grifas

Comment: And if you comment the `phone` variable, do you still have this error ?

Comment: yes. i got same error after commenting phone variable

Comment: if i delete the phone from database the error goes to name variable like this "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Seller.UserObj 0x6000000ec380> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name." @Grifas

Comment: can you show us the result of printing item please

Comment: this is the  result  ["name": Faizul karim, "userId": WXapOXcFv2T5DL0AuJR79cFBqf62, "address": west-razabazar, Dhanmondi,dhaka]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where is the error coming from but here is another way to retrieve data in Firebase, that I tested and I use.

For your Model, you can use the `DataSnapshot`

```
struct UserObj {
    var address: String?
    var name: String?
    var phone: String?
    var userId: String? 

init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    ref = snapshot.ref
    key = snapshot.key
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as ! [String: AnyObject]
    address = snapshot[address] as! String
    name = snapshot[name] as! String
    phone = snapshot[phone] as! String
    userId = snapshot[userId] as! String
 }


}
```

In your function, you can change to this :

```
ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        var newItems: [UserObj] = []

        for item in snapshot.children {
            let userObjItem = UserObj(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newItems.append(userObjItem)
        }
        self.proModel = newItems
        self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: He want to observe `.childAdded`

Comment: i am getting error for key . where from this is come ?? also getting error "Type 'DataSnapshot' has no subscript members"

Comment: I think address/name/phone/userId should be filled from snapshotValue instead of snapshot.